# CSS tables displaying strangely

Tags: css

I am trying to get two columns of content the same height using the CSS tables method. However, for some reason, the first column has extra padding at the bottom, the second column has extra padding at the top.

I am using the same code I usually do and cannot find the source of the problem when inspecting the code. I have double checked my code and look at other examples but cannot find the cause of this problem.

The code I am using is:

```
.archive-post{
    display:table;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:20px 0px;}

.archive-post .left-column{
    display:table-cell;
    width:60%;}

.archive-post .right-column{
    display:table-cell;
    width:40%;
    padding-left:20px;}
```

Or you can see a live link [here.](http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/SilverBirch/office/new-office-entry-5/)

Comment: Please can you include all the relevant code to recreate the issue in your question. A link is not suitable as the question will be of little value to other users if it goes dead/the issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [vertical align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

```
.archive-post .left-column,
.archive-post .right-column {
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

This should to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small idea.. have you tried `flexbox`, for that? It's really a simple and easiest way to do that. Plus you can use position:absolute; inside the columns (`display:table` and `display:table-cell` do not allow that).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 2;
}
main {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.25em 0em;
}
section {
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
aside {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    left column.<br>higher then the other
  </section>
  <aside>
    right column
  </aside>
</main>
```